# Excel: Converting horizontal table into vertical

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, pivot-table

I'm currently working on a table which has 900+ columns and 20 rows. For filtring and query search purpose, I want to convert it into a vertical table with the help of cell reference or pivot or any other live data conversion techniques. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use TRANSPOSE function, function argument should be entry table selected.

to make function work you need to CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER that is insert it as array formula over selected range of cels (900 rows and 20 columns)

HOW TO:
select 900 rows and 20 columns, press F2 type =TRANSPOSE(select table here) and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

[Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027)

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to the correct spelling of SHIFT, I was unable to submit an edit as "you have to change at least 6 characters for an edit"

Answer (score 0):

Select the table, hit Ctrl+C, select a cell below row 21, hit Alt => E => S => V => => E which will transpose your table into 900 rows by 20 columns.

This is an old Excel 2003 shortcut that still works.

If you want the Alt keystrokes for later versions it would be Alt => H => V => S => V => E

Comment: you should at least say what the steps in words. Nobody knows what those keystrokes represents, and the OP didn't ask for a shortcut anyway. This will become invalid if someday the keys are changed

Comment: Alt sequence: h=`Home` tab, v=`Insert`, s=`Special`, v=`Values`, e=`Transpose`, `enter`. Alt sequences are contextual; both to previous keystrokes in the Alt sequence (menu navigation) and the context of the Excel state (cannot paste without having copied or cut).

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the data in the table
2. Copy
3. Go to the cell down the given table

4 Select Paste-Transpose from the Menu